# istanbul ignore next not working for @ContentChildren(ElementRef, {descendants: true}) set inputs(inputs: QueryList<ElementRef>)

Tags: ts-jest, istanbul, ignore

I am trying to write jest test for this function. Since there is no business logic , I would like to ignore the entire function. I tried to ignore it by adding a ignore text before the function and various other places as shown below, but no luck.

```js
/* istanbul ignore next */
@ContentChildren(ElementRef, {descendants: true}) set inputs(inputs: QueryList<ElementRef>) {
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    this._inputs = inputs;
}
```

My jest test coverage says `inputs(` is not covered. Any clue how to ignore this? I have tried this `@ContentChildren(ElementRef, {descendants: true}) set  /* istanbul ignore next */ inputs(inputs: QueryList<ElementRef>)` but no luck.